# Boundary box not updating correctly

Tags: android

As an intro, my app is a flappy bird style game. You have fire at the bottom and  top of the screen, You have to jump at the right time in order not to get hit. You have 3 different ice cream cones. Each a different height. Whenever the icecream collides with the fire, it goes down in height.

The issue I am having is whenever the icecream reduces in height, the boundary box seems to not get updated, even though I assumed that my updateRect() logic is correct.
In regards to the top boundary of the icecream and the bottom boundary of the fire, The icecreams with the smaller heights appear as they are suppose to visually on the screen, but their bounding box seems to match that of the tallest icecreams.

I noticed this because it seems as if I can get pretty close to the fires at the top without colliding when I'm using the tallest icecream. But when I use the shorter icecreams, I can still collide even though the gap seems bigger than compared to the tallest.

These are the codes I believe to be relevant to this issue

```
private InfJIceCream iceCream;
private ArrayList<Fire> lowFires;
private ArrayList<Fire> highFires;

private static int IC1_HEIGHT = 77;
private static int IC2_HEIGHT= 102;
private static int IC3_HEIGHT = 127;

private static int FIRE_WIDTH = 60;
private static int FIRE_HEIGHT = 60;




@Override
    public void init() {
         /* In order to align the icecream properly on the y-axis, I replaced 45(The height of the ground) with 44 because
        * when 45 is part of the equation, it seems as if the iceCreams drops for a bit when initialized
        * or does some sort of funny business
        *
        * This detail is virtually irrelevant but I feel as if 44 does a better job in making sure
        * the iceCream is on the ground at the beginning of the gameplay
        */

//InfJIceCream(x,y,width,height);

        iceCream = new InfJIceCream(160, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 44
                - IC3_HEIGHT, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);
        lowFires = new ArrayList<Fire>();
        highFires = new ArrayList<Fire>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Fire lowFire = new Fire(i * 200, Fire.LOWER_Y, FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            Fire highFire = new Fire(i * 300, Fire.UPPER_Y, FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            lowFires.add(i, lowFire);
            highFires.add(i, highFire);

        }

        iceCream3 = true;
    }




 private void renderFire(Painter g) {

    for (Fire fire : lowFires) {
        if (fire.isVisible()) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.fire, (int) fire.getX(), (int) fire.getY(), FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                fire.resetLow();
            }
        }
    }
    for (Fire fire : highFires) {
        if (fire.isVisible()) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.fire, (int) fire.getX(), (int) fire.getY(), FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                fire.resetHigh();
            }
        }
    }
}




 private void renderIceCream(Painter g) {
        /*
         iceCream3 is true by default
         */

//Checking for collisions with the fire on the ground
        for (Fire fire : lowFires){

            if (iceCream3) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);


                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream3 = false;
                    iceCream2 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream2) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream2 = false;
                    iceCream1 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream1) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore/100));

                }
            }}

// Checking for collisions with the fire above gounnd.
    for (Fire fire : highFires){

            if (iceCream3) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);


                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream3 = false;
                    iceCream2 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream2) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream2 = false;
                    iceCream1 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream1) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore/100));

                }
            }}
    }
```

This is the Whole class.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.view.MotionEvent;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import rect.draw.gametest.Assets;
import rect.draw.gametest.GameMainActivity;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.Fire;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.InfJIceCream;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.util.Painter;

public class HardState extends State {
    private InfJIceCream iceCream;
    private ArrayList<Fire> lowFires;
    private ArrayList<Fire> highFires;

    private int cloudX = 0;
    private int cloudY = 100;



    private int playerScore = 1;

    private int fireSpeed = -200;
    private static int ICECREAM_WIDTH = 38;
    private static int IC1_HEIGHT = 77;
    private static int IC2_HEIGHT= 102;
    private static int IC3_HEIGHT = 127;

    private static int FIRE_WIDTH = 60;
    private static int FIRE_HEIGHT = 60;

    public boolean iceCream1,iceCream2,iceCream3;


    private float recentTouchY;
    @Override
    public void init() {
         /* In order to align the icecream properly on the y-axis, I replaced 45(The height of the ground) with 44 because
        * when 45 is part of the equation, it seems as if the iceCreams drops for a bit when initialized
        * or does some sort of funny business
        *
        * This detail is virtually irrelevant but I feel as if 44 does a better job in making sure
        * the iceCream is on the ground at the beginning of the gameplay
        */

        iceCream = new InfJIceCream(160, GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 44
                - IC3_HEIGHT, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);
        lowFires = new ArrayList<Fire>();
        highFires = new ArrayList<Fire>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // The y position initialization for the fires are irrelevant because they are invisible
            // until the resetLow() method is called. Which will then change the y position

            Fire lowFire = new Fire(i * 200, Fire.LOWER_Y, FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            Fire highFire = new Fire(i * 300, Fire.UPPER_Y, FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
            lowFires.add(i, lowFire);
            highFires.add(i, highFire);

        }

        iceCream3 = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        for(Fire fire: lowFires){
            fire.update(delta, fireSpeed);

        }

        for(Fire fire: highFires){
            fire.update(delta,fireSpeed);
        }
        playerScore += 1;
        iceCream.update(delta);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(30, 144, 255));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);

        renderSun(g);
        renderClouds(g);

        g.drawImage(Assets.mountains, 0, 81);
        g.drawImage(Assets.grass, 0, 405);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        renderSwipeUp(g);
        renderFire(g);
        renderScore(g);
        renderIceCream(g);
    }

    private void renderSwipeUp(Painter g){

        for(Fire fire : lowFires) {

            if (!fire.isVisible()) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.swipeUp, 200, 15, 200, 230);
            }

// All fires in the Array have to return isVisible = true before the swipeUp image goes away
        }

    }

    private void renderScore(Painter g) {
        g.setFont(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, 25);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("" + playerScore / 100, 20, 30);

    }



    private void renderFire(Painter g) {

        for (Fire fire : lowFires) {
            if (fire.isVisible()) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.fire, (int) fire.getX(), (int) fire.getY(), FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
                if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    fire.resetLow();
                }
            }
        }
        for (Fire fire : highFires) {
            if (fire.isVisible()) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.fire, (int) fire.getX(), (int) fire.getY(), FIRE_WIDTH, FIRE_HEIGHT);
                if (Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    fire.resetHigh();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void renderIceCream(Painter g) {
        /*
         iceCream3 is true by default
         */

        //Checking for collisions with the fire on the ground
        for (Fire fire : lowFires){

            if (iceCream3) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);


                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream3 = false;
                    iceCream2 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream2) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream2 = false;
                    iceCream1 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream1) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore/100));

                }
            }}

        // Checking for collisions with the fire above gounnd.
    for (Fire fire : highFires){

            if (iceCream3) {
                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream3, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY(), ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC3_HEIGHT);


                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream3 = false;
                    iceCream2 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream2) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream2, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 25, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC2_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    iceCream2 = false;
                    iceCream1 = true;

                }
            } else if (iceCream1) {

                g.drawImage(Assets.iceCream1, (int) iceCream.getX(), (int) iceCream.getY() + 50, ICECREAM_WIDTH, IC1_HEIGHT);

                if (fire.isVisible() && Rect.intersects(iceCream.getRect(), fire.getRect())) {
                    setCurrentState(new GameOverState(playerScore/100));

                }
            }}
    }

    private void renderSun(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
        g.fillOval(715, -85, 170, 170);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(725, -75, 150, 150);
    }

    private void renderClouds(Painter g) {
        g.drawImage(Assets.cloud1, cloudX, cloudY, 100, 60);
        cloudX += 4;

        if (cloudX > 950) {
            cloudX = -100;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            recentTouchY = scaledY;
        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (scaledY - recentTouchY < -50) {
                iceCream.jump();
            } else if (scaledY - recentTouchY > 50) {

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```